# Using 2 uipickerview in 1 viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app I developed where I’m using two pickerview boxes using the tag property: one for gender and one for a list of items. Once I choose either pickerview, it somehow increments the other pickerview to an entry with an actual value and doesn’t start from the empty entry I created at [0]. I make my first selection and when I go into the 2nd list it’s already sitting on 50-55 (first entry with a value and sits at [1](https://youtu.be/JnHii-c1E3M). If i don't move from [1](https://youtu.be/JnHii-c1E3M) to another and then back to [1](https://youtu.be/JnHii-c1E3M) the label is still blank. If i click off of pre-selected item and go back to it, all works fine. Pasting the pickerview code below - let me know if more info is needed and thanks in advance!

[Added a video as to what exactly is happening:](https://youtu.be/JnHii-c1E3M)

```
let gendOption = ["", "Male","Female"] // first array for first textfield  
let actOption = ["", "50%-55%", "55%-60%", "60%-65%", "65%-70%", "70%-75%", "75%-80%", "80%-85%", "85%-90%", "90%-95%"] // array for 2nd textfield


let pickerView = UIPickerView()  
var currentTxtFldTag : Int = 10  


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {  
    return 1  
}  

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {  
    // return priorityTypes.count  
    if currentTxtFldTag == 10  
    {  
        return gendOption.count  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return actOption.count  
    }  
}  

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {  
    // return priorityTypes[row]  
    if currentTxtFldTag == 10  
    {  
        return gendOption[row]  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return actOption[row]  
    }  
}  

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {  
    //selectedPriority = priorityTypes[row]  
    //activityTextBox.text = selectedPriority  
    if currentTxtFldTag == 10  
    {  
        genderSelection.text = gendOption[row]  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        activityTextBox.text = actOption[row]  

    }  
}  

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  

    if textField.tag == 10  // *** OPTION  
    {  
        currentTxtFldTag = 10  
    }  
    else  // activity OPTION  
    {  
        currentTxtFldTag = 20  
    }  

    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()  
    return true  
}  

func createPickerView() {  
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()  
    pickerView.delegate = self  
    activityTextBox.inputView = pickerView  
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this `currentTxtFldTag` flag to see which `pickerView` you're referring to, just save each `pickerView` as a variable and check which `pickerView` you're referring to directly in each of your delegate methods, like so:

```
lazy var genderPickerView: UIPickerView = {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    picker.delegate = self
    return picker
}()

lazy var otherPickerView: UIPickerView = {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    picker.delegate = self
    return picker
}()

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {    
    // Use this check in each of your delegate methods for UIPickerViewDelegate
    if pickerView == genderPickerView
    {  
        genderSelection.text = gendOption[row]  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        activityTextBox.text = actOption[row]  

    }  
}
```

Comment: thank you.  when setting the variables with your example, i get this error using xcode 10.2.1:
Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Comment: edited my original post to include a video link as to exactly whats happening

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the closure return type (as well as the `()` after the enclosure, and that they should be `lazy` to use `self`). Edited above answer to include it. Should fix that problem